# WordPress: How to hide specific Gutenberg blocks settings from users

Tags: wordpress, gutenberg-blocks

There are any way to hide some Gutenberg block settings from users?

Like " Crop images, Link To and Additional CSS class"

[image]

Comment: I didn't test this plugin (https://wordpress.org/plugins/secure-blocks-for-gutenberg/) but this seems like it can solve your problem.

Comment: You can also use WordPress REST API to get info about the capabilities of the user and then use the state of React component inside edit method to hide or show the controls.

Comment: Thank you @MehmoodAhmed for your reply, but I don't need to hide post content! I'm talking about the blocks settings as it shown in the image above, btw.. do you have some examples code for your second suggestion? of how can i hide blocks settings by using REST API. Thanks again.